# bind css class dynamically from database to div tag in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

i am creating labels dynamically in list view, the labels are placed inside the div tag and i want the cssclass of the label to be changed for each label. i am getting names of the label dynamically from database and that database contains cssclasses for each name. so how can i bind the cssclass dynamically to the div tag? following is the code

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="sidebar-links">
            <div class="link-blue">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-archive"></i><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<% #Bind ("mdl_name") %>' ></asp:Label></a>

            </div>
            </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

This is the codebehind

```
DataTable dt1 = (DataTable)Session["SessionUserInfo"];

String type = dt1.Rows[0]["user_id"].ToString();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=BABA; Database=afaqandco; Integrated Security=true");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ma.*, m.* FROM tblmdluserassociation AS ma INNER JOIN tbl_module AS m ON ma.mdl_id=m.mdl_id WHERE ma.user_id='"+type+"'", conn);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        ListView1.DataSource = dt;
        ListView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: You'll want to look into the ListView's [ItemDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) event

Comment: can you specify how? @zgood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add ItemDataBound method to the list view and then create it in code behind as follows:

```
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemplaceholder" OnItemDataBound="ListViewMenu_ItemDataBound">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemplaceholder" runat="server" />
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="sidebar-links">
                <div id="MYDIV" runat="server">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-archive"></i>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<% #Bind("mdl_name") %>'></asp:Label></a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Code Behind

```
    protected void ListViewMenu_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        ListViewDataItem listViewDataItem = e.Item as ListViewDataItem;
        HtmlGenericControl divControl = e.Item.FindControl("MYDIV") as HtmlGenericControl;
        DataRowView dataRow = ((DataRowView)listViewDataItem.DataItem);
        divControl.Attributes.Add("class", dataRow["CLASS"].ToString());
    }

}
```

Comment: you are welcome, please accept it as the best answer.